# Delete WebApi FromURI binding

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a .NET5 WebApi delete method in a controller class where this method receives several "ids" that will be used for deleting some entities.

I realized when building the delete request on the client side that specifying a content does not make sense. So I was guided to pass ids on the Uri, hence the use of the ["FromUri" attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

```
// DELETE: api/ProductionOrders/5
[HttpDelete("ProductionOrders")]
public IActionResult DeleteProductionOrder([System.Web.Http.FromUri]int[] ids)
{
    //code
}
```

If this is a reasonable approach, is there a better way to build this Uri from the client-side? Imagine instead of an array of ints I had a complex type. How can I serialized this and put into the Uri?

For this example I end up building up a URI like this:

```
http://localhost:51081/api/ProductionOrders?ids=25563&ids=25533
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, if I have to pass a List or a complex type I would map values from the Body via JSON. The DELETE allow using body. And then just decorate your param with `[FromBody]` attribute.

*Despite some recommendations not to use the message body for DELETE requests, this approach may be appropriate in certain use cases.*

This allows better extensibility in case you need to change how the data is coming.

In your case with ids I’d create new class like this:

```
public class RequestEntity {
  [JsonPropertyName("Ids")]
  public List<int> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

And then when calling this method, send the Body along with the request.

```
{ 
  "Ids": [25392, 254839, 25563]
}
```

In a future you can pass complex objects just by changing what is send to server and implement complex logic.